# Swift: Choose queue for Bluetooth Central manager

Tags: ios, swift, queue, grand-central-dispatch, core-bluetooth

I'm working on the app that will connect with a smart device via BLE and communicate with it.

The question is: **In what queue is the best practice to handle bluetooth events?**

I've read a lot of tutorials and in all of them I found this:

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```

They choose to handle bluetooth events in **main queue** (`queue: nil`), but I suppose that it's not good practice. Because it could be a lot of queries send to peripheral device from central and a lot of answers send from peripheral to central.

I assume this might be the reason of the app working slowly and might detrimentally affect the productivity, am I right?

Will this flood the UI update queue?

Comment: In example from raywenderlich I find this:
 `let centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.raywenderlich", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)`
`centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: centralQueue)`

Is it the bast solution?

Comment: Can you share the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>I am using dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0) for the CBCentralManager for some time in my Bluetooth projects and it is working flawlessly.</s>

^ Scratch that. I wouldn't recommend using the global queue. The reason is that the global queue is a concurrent one and you probably want a serial one. Create a new `DispatchQueue(label: "CentralManager")` and pass it to the `CBCentralManager`.

All the delegate methods will be delivered to the queue you specify. If you do some very light operations on these methods, I guess you could keep the main queue. But it is better to use a background queue.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use a seperate queue for the `CBCentralManager` and preferrably also use it for all the communication with the `CBPeripheral` object - so your main queue is not getting blocked.

`dispatch_async` the events to your queue should not be a problem - as long as read/write requests are not getting delayed.

Answer (score -2):

From Bluetooth perspective, I don't think queue the events is a best practice; except you want to delay the sending messages.